# String Data type and sum time duration using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I have is a string data type which stores the duration.

I am a looking for sum of the duration and then average of that sum.

I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Example:

```
00:30:21
00:40:01
00:21:10
```

Model class

```
public DateTime? FeedbackDateTime { get; set; }

public DateTime? FeedbackSharedDateTime { get; set; }

public string AuditorAHT { get; set; }
```

ReportVM To Group Data and display in the View

```
public string FeedbackSharedBy { get; set; }
public int AuditCount { get; set; }

public string AudtAht { get; set; }
```

Controller that saves the action perform by auditor as duration in

```
public string AuditorAHT { get; set; }
```

```
dto.FeedbackSharedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

string ahtString = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", dto.FeedbackSharedDateTime - dto.FeedbackDateTime);

dto.AuditorAHT = ahtString;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Below Action should display Auditors Name, Count, and Average Time spent. From which Name and Count is working but not the Average Time Spend

```
var audtName = db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= mostRecentMonday
                           && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= weekEnd && x.Feedback != null && x.FeedbackSharedBy != null).Select(x => new {
x.FeedbackSharedBy,
x.AuditorAHT
}).ToList() // this hits the database
                            
// We need to do grouping in the code (rather than the db)
// because timespans are stored as strings
.GroupBy(e => e.FeedbackSharedBy)
.Select(g => new ReportVM
{
FeedbackSharedBy = g.Key,
AuditCount = g.Count(),
AudtAht = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Sum(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.AuditorAHT).TotalSeconds / g.Count())).ToString()
})
.OrderByDescending(s => s.AuditCount).ToList();

ViewBag.AudtReport = audtName;
```

Above COde is working for me, managed to make it work.

Comment: To do math (sum, average) with durations, you should represent them as `TimeSpan` instead of `string`.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. Duration is outcome of DateTime1 - DateTIme2. I tried using TImeSpan data type instead but itdid not allow me to do this TimeSpan duration = DateTime2 - DateTime1. Thats why I chose string Data Type

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't allow me'?

Comment: Can you show the class behind `Chats` ?

Comment: `TimeSpan duration = DateTime2 - DateTime1` should work fine (assuming that DateTime1 and DateTime2 are of type `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`),

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string duration into a `TimeSpan` type and use this to do time calculations. To convert it you can use `TimeSpan.Parse()` or if you have a fix format use `TimeSpan.ParseExact()`.

With `TimeSpan` you can get the the totals out of it with the various `.Total*()` methods. You also can get the internal ticks count with `.Ticks`. That's the one with the highest precision.

Now its a simple math: `sum of all ticks / count = average ticks`

You can pass this average ticks count into a `TimeSpan` again to grab it as `.TotalMilliseconds()` or output it formatted with `.ToString()`.

Here is a basic sample:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var duration1 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:30:21");
        var duration2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:40:01");
        var duration3 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:21:10");
        
        var totalDuration = duration1.Add(duration2).Add(duration3);
        var averageDurationTicks = totalDuration.Ticks / 3;
        var averageDuration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(averageDurationTicks);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Total duration: {totalDuration}, Average duration: {averageDuration}");
    }
}
```

Here is a .Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Q9tmV

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try your Code too, but some how my code is not giving me result. I updated my query with my complete code. Hope that will help. THank you again.

Comment: @RS Did you try the dotnetfiddle link?

Comment: Thank  you! No, I did not but this is now fixed. I did update my working above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If a second precision is enough for you you could combine Linq's Sum and Average with TimeSpan's Parse and TotalSeconds:

```
Sum = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Sum(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.Time).TotalSeconds)),
Avg = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Average(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.Time).TotalSeconds))
```

Here is a full example:

```
var data = new []{
    new { X = "A", Time = "00:30:21"},
    new { X = "B", Time = "00:40:01"},
    new { X = "B", Time = "00:21:10"}
    };

var grouped = data
    .GroupBy(e => e.X)
    .Select( g => new {
        X = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        Sum = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Sum(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.Time).TotalSeconds)),
        Avg = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Average(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.Time).TotalSeconds))     
    });

foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"'{item.X}' has {item.Count} item(s), sum = {item.Sum}, avg = {item.Avg}");
}
```

This produces:

```
'A' has 1 item(s), sum = 00:30:21, avg = 00:30:21
'B' has 2 item(s), sum = 01:01:11, avg = 00:30:35.5000000
```

You could use `TotalMilliseconds` + `FromMillisecond` or even go super precise `Ticks`.

### Variant with `Aggregate`

Another option is to Parse earlier:

```
Sum = g.Select(e => TimeSpan.Parse(e.Time)).Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1 + t2),
Avg = g.Select(e => TimeSpan.Parse(e.Time)).Aggregate((t1, t2) => t1 + t2) / g.Count()
```

## For LINQ to Entities

As you report in your comment if we try the above with your real code it results in *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromSeconds(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.* (With the same for `TimeSpan.Parse`.

Because of this we will would need to do the grouping in the code. This is less efficient that if the TimeSpan was in the database as TimeSpan.

```
var grouped = db.Chats
    .Where(...)
    .Select( x => new {
        x.FeedbackSharedBy,
        x.AuditorAHT 
    })
    .ToList() // this hits the database
    // We need to do grouping in the code (rather than the db)
    // because timespans are stored as strings
    .GroupBy(e => e.FeedbackSharedBy)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        FeedbackSharedBy = g.Key,
        AuditCount = g.Count(),
        AuditorAHTSumSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Sum(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.AuditorAHT).TotalSeconds) / g.Count())
            .ToString(),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.AuditCount)
    .ToList(); // Optional
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I did try code, but still no success. I updated my query with my complete Code, hope that will help and may be can get an outcome. Can you please take a look?

Comment: var audtName = db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start
                           && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end && x.Feedback != null && x.FeedbackSharedBy != null).GroupBy(a => a.AuditorName).Select(b => new ReportVM()
{
FeedbackSharedBy = b.Key,
AuditCount = b.Count(),
AudtAht = b.Sum(c =>
{
 return String.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", c.AuditorAHT) ;
})
}).ToList(); Tried this but no success

Comment: Is AudtAht the average?

Comment: Yes, this is Average which will render on View

Comment: `AudtAht = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Average(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.Time).TotalSeconds)).ToString()`. I'm not sure if LinqToSql will handle that though. Let me know if get a runtime error.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromSeconds(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
Here is the error

Comment: Ok, we'll have to do i in two stages. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let me know how it went.

Comment: Thank you! a quick question. Do I have to create new data type in ReportVM "AuditorAHTSumSeconds", if yes what should be its Datatype?

Comment: No you don't. The intermediate type is anonymous. Please note the 1st select is  `=> new {` and only the second is with `=> new ReportVM`.

Comment: Getting squigly line , see the screen shot here https://prnt.sc/119jsyt

Comment: I am stuck with squiggly line , see the screen shot here prnt.sc/119jsyt  . Kindly take a look here

Comment: Try: `AudtAht = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x.AuditorAHTSumSeconds / x.AuditCount).ToString()`

Comment: Still seeing same error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/119nzcl . Kindly help

Comment: Ok, it seems that this will be hard without storing TimeSpan as TimeSpan OR bringing up all rows that match Where and doing the grouping in the code. I'll update the answer with grouping in the code

Comment: :( No success, stays at squiggly line, see the error here please https://prnt.sc/11afu8p

Comment: We just need to move one ")"

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to find the extra ")"

Comment: Thank you every so much, modified the Code little bit and got the result. I did update the Code so can come handy to some one else. Thank you again, for being so patient with me, and so quick with your response. You are awesome and a lovely person.

Comment: Why am I seeing this error https://prnt.sc/11btyns . THis happens only when I change mostRecentMonday TO lastWeekMonday, and weekEnd TO lastWeekSunday. var mostRecentMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
            var weekEnd = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); var lastWeekMonday = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(-7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
            var lastWeekSunday = lastWeekMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of time and with help of tymtam made the code work with below code.

```
var audtName = db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= mostRecentMonday
                           && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= weekEnd && x.Feedback != null && x.FeedbackSharedBy != null).Select(x => new {
x.FeedbackSharedBy,
x.AuditorAHT
}).ToList() // this hits the database
                            
// We need to do grouping in the code (rather than the db)
// because timespans are stored as strings
.GroupBy(e => e.FeedbackSharedBy)
.Select(g => new ReportVM
{
FeedbackSharedBy = g.Key,
AuditCount = g.Count(),
AudtAht = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Sum(t => TimeSpan.Parse(t.AuditorAHT).TotalSeconds / g.Count())).ToString()
})
.OrderByDescending(s => s.AuditCount).ToList();

ViewBag.AudtReport = audtName;
```